# Appsync Invoke lambda after response?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

**Example Problem:**

A user can post their own articles on our website. However, each user can only post 5 articles and when they post their 5th article, we want to send them an email.

---

Using revolvers only, is it possible to return the mutation response on time and then lazily/async invoke a lambda function that sends an email to the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that should be very possible. It depends a bit on what kind of resolver you want to use. If you were using a Lambda data source:

- As you mentioned, Lambda invocations can be [asynchronous](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-options.html), so
  you could execute one inside a Lambda resolver and see minimal additional overhead.
- You could use Lambda event sourcing. For example, earlier this year, Lambda launched [SQS event-based Lambda invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/aws-lambda-now-supports-amazon-sqs-as-event-source/). What that means is, your Lambda resolver would put a message with some event context into an SQS queue (such as account info, email address...etc.), and then you'd have a Lambda that listens to that queue. It automagically polls, so it would invoke immediately and parse that message, and you'd send the email from that.
- There's additional Lambda event sources that you could find helpful based on personal preferences/application needs, all of which are visible in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html). Specifically, you might find SNS and/or Kinesis to be viable options. Conceptually they're the same - your resolver pushes a message into some AWS service, and the event-driven Lambda will automatically be invoked.

If you were using a DynamoDB data source:

- You could set up DynamoDB streams on your table and hook up an event-driven Lambda that listens to that stream.

In any case, you might find [pipeline resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html) to be useful. It allows you to set up a linear, synchronous chain of resolvers to solve some more complex problems. You could have an initial Lambda function/DDB lookup to get the number of posts (and potentially fail if someone is at their limit), then a second resolver after that to do your normal action, then potentially even a third that could send the email that someone has hit the limit.

Comment: Wow I had never seen DynamoDB streams before. I think for my case this is the perfect solution and maintains the clean organisation of tasks that I'm looking for.

Also very interested in the pipeline resolvers. I'll give both a shot and see what works best. Thank you for the super clear answer. There is so much on AWS its hard to know it all!